# How to retain data in JSON object while switching from one Dialog to other in MS Bot Framework

Tags: c#, .net, json, dialog, botframework

I am trying to build a bot using MS Bot Framework and I have two dialogs (Parent and Child). I am getting JSON response from a web api in ParentDialog and mapping it to data-model class WebResults. Based on some special activity I have to switch to ChildDialog, and there I need DataResults.title string. But after switching to ChildDialog all the data mapping goes back to null. Is there a way to I can get DataResults.title string in ChildDialog?

Following is my MessageController

```
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new ParentDialog());

        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;


   }
```

Parent Dialog

```
public class ParentDialog : IDialog
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(ActivityReceivedAsync); 
    }


    private async  Task ActivityReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {

        var activity = await result as Activity;

        webApiResponse = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(Uri);
        webApiJsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WebResults>(webApiResponse);
        DataResult[] infoResult = wikiJsonResponse.query.pages;

    If (activity.Text == "Something Special") 
    {
        await context.Forward(new ChildDialog(), ActivityReceivedAsync, activity, CancellationToken.None);
    } 
    else
    {
        //some handling on inforesult
        await context.PostAsync(replyMessage);
        context.Done(false);
    }

}
```

Child Dialog

```
public class ChildDialog : IDialog
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(ActivityReceivedAsync); 
    }


    private async  Task ActivityReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {

       DataResult data = new DataResult(); //Goes null
       string pageTiltle = data.title;

       // Some handling with pageTitle

       context.Done(true);
   }
```

Data Model

```
public class WebResults
{
    public string batchcomplete { get; set; }
    public Query query { get; set; }
}

public class Query
{
    public DataResult[] pages { get; set; }
}

public class DataResult
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public Coordinate[] coordinates { get; set; }
    public string extract { get; set; }
    public Thumbnail thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string pageimage { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first problem that you are having is that in the ChildDialog you are creating a new instance of the DataResult, reason why the properties are null.

One alternative, would be to pass to the ChildDialog the DataResult array that you are building in the ParentDialog. You can pass it via the constructor, so in the context.Forward line you would do something like:

```
await context.Forward(new ChildDialog(infoResult), ActivityReceivedAsync, activity, CancellationToken.None);
```

Another way to solve it, would be using the BotBuilder state data bags, coming out of the box. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-State) you will find an example on how to use the state bags and here the [core concepts](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/core-concepts/userdata/#navtitle) around them.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Seems like you are the only one who answers Bot framework questions  over here :)